# Is it safe to comment out the "custom-set-variables" part in your init file?

Tags: init-file, customization

Recently I had some font lock mess with auctex (similar to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/g95vyl/font_lock_in_auctex_messed_up/)). To solve the problem I commented out my init file part for part and realized that the problem is inside the custom-set-variables section.

I just realized that this section contains much clutter I don't need anymore (long time ago when I started using emacs I used the graphical customization interface, but I don't use it anymore today and configure everything via elisp in my init file directly).

So, is it safe to comment out or delete this section?

Comment: You need to check that all the settings are duplicated, but yes, there is nothing special about it: you can delete or comment out entries that you dont' need or delete the whole thing or comment it out. The only danger is that you lose a setting that is not duplicated in your init file, but if you are careful, you can avoid such nasty surprises.

Comment: @NickD: Please consider posting your comment as an answer. Comments can be deleted at any time.